# Dropdownlist avoid postback in c#

Tags: c#

I have a dropdownlist control (ddl) on gridview.

There are these values in the ddl control "A" and "B" and "C".

I need to avoid postback of the page when selected value in dropdownlist control (ddl) is changed.

And this is working.

But this code is not working because it's no longer possible to edit the gridview line and the `CommandName="Edit"` in the gridview has stopped working.

```html
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvProducts"
                                  EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="gvProducts" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            EmptyDataText="no data" EnableViewState="true"
            runat="server" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" 
            HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrows" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EDIT" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit" 
                             CommandName="Edit" runat="server"
                             ImageUrl="/Images/Edit.gif"
                             OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm ?');" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server"
                             ID="ddl"
                             AutoPostBack="true"
                             OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
               <Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**EDIT**

```cs
protected void gvProducts_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    string sID = gvProducts.DataKeys[e.NewEditIndex].Value.ToString();

    string queryString = "sDetails.aspx?sID=" + sID.ToString().ToUpper();
    string newWin = "var Mleft = (screen.width/2)-(1200/2);var Mtop = (screen.height/2)-(700/2);window.open('" + queryString + "','_blank','height=700,width=1200,status=yes,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,location=no,top=\'+Mtop+\', left=\'+Mleft+\';');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "pop", newWin, true);
}

protected void ddl_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)(((Control)sender).NamingContainer);
    string sIDdataKey = this.gvProducts.DataKeys[gvr.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    DropDownList duty = (DropDownList)gvr.FindControl("ddl");

    sql = String.Format(@" UPDATE `tbl` ");
    sql += String.Format(" SET `Letter`= ? ");
    sql += String.Format(" WHERE ID= ?; ");

    using (OdbcConnection cn =
            new OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        using (OdbcCommand command =
                new OdbcCommand(sql, cn))
        {
            try
            {
                command.Connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param1", duty.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("param2", sIDdataKey.ToString());
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                BindData();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                command.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to help if you can post your actual source code. The other ItemTemplates and `EditItemTemplate`s are missing.

Comment: @OguzOzgul The other `ItemTemplates` and `EditItemTemplates` not are missing, because the editing it's not executed in the gridview, but on a different webpage opened in the window popup. Please see **EDIT** in question.

Comment: Now you have unmatched `<Columns>`.

Comment: @GSerg So sorry copy/paste code error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can help you.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    EmptyDataText="no data" EnableViewState="true"
    runat="server"
    DataKeyNames="ID"
    HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrows" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EDIT" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtnEdit"
                    CommandName="Edit" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl="/Images/Edit.gif"
                    OnClientClick="return confirm('Confirm ?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="List" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gvProducts"
                            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server"
                            ID="ddl"
                            AutoPostBack="true"
                            OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="A" Value="A" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="B" Value="B" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="C" Value="C" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```